# My form submission not working

Tags: php, email, post

### HTML Codes

```
                        <h3>online consultation</h3>

                        <h5>We have provided contact information down below. You can contact us either by mobile, via email or via contact form. We will at once contact you to discuss your problems! If you have special requirments a consultation can be decided.</h5>


                        </div>


                                  <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-offset-3 contact-grid-right">                     

                             <form  method="post" action="mail.php">

                               <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="name" id="name" required="required">

                               <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email" id="Email" required="required">

                                   <input type="text" placeholder="Contact No" name="contact" id="contact" required="required">

                              <input type="text" placeholder="Subject"  name="subject" id="subject" required="required">

                              <textarea rows="2" cols="70" type="text" placeholder="MESSAGE"  name="message" id="message" required="required">

                                                           </textarea>


                          <button type="submit" class="slide-btn"> Send your message <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> <br></button>                                 


                         </form>


                         </div>
```

### PHP Script

```
<?php

$n=$_POST['name'];
$mail=$_POST['email'];
$ph=$_POST['contact'];
$ln=$_POST['subject'];
$msg=$_POST['message'];
$to="email@yahoo.com";
$sub="message";

$body="
<html>
    <body>
        <p><b></b></p><h4></h4>
        <table border='0'>
            <tr>
                <b>Name : </b> $n <br><br>
                <b>Email : </b> $mail <br><br>
                <b>Contact :</b> $ph  <br><br>
                <b>Subject :</b> $ln <br><br>
                <hr>
                <b>Contact Form Message:</b> <br><br>$msg 
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>";


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0". "\r\n";

$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8". "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From:'.$mail . "\r\n";

//$headers .= 'Cc: email@yahoo.com.au'; "\r\n";

//$headers .= 'Bcc: '; "\r\n";

mail($to,$sub,$body,$headers);

//echo "<script>alert('Message Send Sucessfully')</script>";

echo "<script>window.location.href='index.html'</script>";



?>
```

Comment: Please do a proper format on your code.

Comment: And tell us what exactly is not working

Comment: Message is not receiving when filled in the contact form!!

Comment: I am not able to post php script here! what should I do???

Comment: Ok, it has finally appeared!!

Comment: @Aryan Please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You are unlikely to get helpful answers the way you posted this "question" (there actually isn't even a question here).

Answer (score 0):

here the solution change the $mail=$_POST['email']; in your php script to $mail=$_POST['Email'];

Comment: Ok, so I have finally discovered the problem! It is - when I am putting '@' in the box in the contact form I do not receiving any message to my webmail but when I drop '@' the whole message of the contact form arrive my web mail. what's this strange problem????

Answer (score 0):

For keeping your code standard replace the email html input for:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" required="required">
```